# Extract ALL the web elements of a page using SELENIUM

Tags: selenium

Is there a way to extract all the web elements loaded in a web page?

For example, I am login to amazon after successful login. In the search page, I am looking for "Samsung phones" between price  and  and clicking the go button from the left side of the page where we apply filters. After clicking the go button, I see results are displayed. 
Now if the search result displays 6 samsung phones, is there a way to extract all the webelements displayed on the page and perform a check to see if the prices of the displayed phones are between  and

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using amazon site, please find the below code to get all the phones searched:

```
List<WebElement> allPhones = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='a-row a-spacing-base']"));
for(WebElement eachPhone : allPhones) {
    System.out.println("Searched phone name is: " + eachPhone.getText());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Karthik - it worked well. Also please let me know if there is a way to extract only the price of the phones? Currently I am getting the result like this                                                                                               Search result is :Refurbished Samsung Galaxy Note 5 N920G (Silver Titanium, 32GB)
by Samsung
Search result is :  32,499.00offer(1 offer)

Comment: @Bimlesh, You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, can you please mark this as Answer

Comment: @Karthik - below code from amazon.in website is returning me both the phone names and prices. Is there a way to extract only the prices of the phone? Please advise

List<WebElement> result = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-mini']"));
  
  for(WebElement res : result)
  {
   System.out.println("Search result is :"+res.getText());
  }

Comment: @Bimlesh, Use the below xpath to identify the prices `.//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-price s-price a-text-bold']`